# Angular Unit Testing - Mocking methods/closures in same service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, sinon

I'm currently trying to unit test my angular service using [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/), but have been running into an issue and was hoping someone could possibly shed some light on why this is occurring. I have reconstructed my current project to illustrate the problem at hand.

I have also provided a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/XG3SLLedDK64Ta9llc7T?p=preview)

I have a service, `peopleService`:

```
(function (){

  angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('peopleService', peopleService);

    peopleService.$inject = ['$q'];

    function peopleService ($q){
      var people = ['Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie'];

      // in actual project, this makes an http request
      function getFamily () {
         return people;
      }

      function getAdults (){
        var family = getFamily();
        return family.filter(function (person){
          return person === 'Homer' || person === 'Marge';
        });
      }

      return {
        getFamily: getFamily,
        getAdults: getAdults
      }
    }

}());
```

In this service, my method `getAdults` uses `getFamily`, filters the results, and returns the data.

In my unit test, I am trying to mock `getFamily` and see if that method is being called. Now this is where the problem presents itself...

First thing I tried was stubbing out the method and overwriting the current method, like so:

```
beforeEach(function (){
  module('myApp');

  inject(function (_peopleService_){
    peopleService = _peopleService_; // get the service
    sinon.stub(peopleService, 'getFamily'); // stub it
  });
});
```

I then go to test whether `getAdults` calls the `getFamily` method:

```
it('getAdults should call "getFamily" once', function(){
     peopleService.getAdults();
     expect(peopleService.getFamily.calledOnce).toBe(true);
});
```

The test fails and the stubbed method is not called...

I debug and find out that although the function has in fact changed:
[image]

The service still holds a reference (closure) to what the method used to be when the service was created:

[image]

My initial thought was I didn't stub the method correctly. I then attempted overwriting the method using [`$provide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) (`$provide.value`) as well as [`$injector decorator`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator) and I ended up getting the same result (closure held onto the original method).

A solution to this would be to use `this`:

```
 function getAdults (){
    var family = this.getFamily(); // <-- by using this.getFamily would reference the mock
    return family.filter(function (person){
      return person === 'Homer' || person === 'Marge';
    });
  }
```

However, I do not understand why I have to do this.

In short, does anyone know:

- how to mock another method in the same service without having to use `this`
- how to mock out a closure variable in a unit test

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: seems your plunker is not available anymore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you stub a method on an object, the *property* of that object is overriden, not the original function that it references.

Take, for example, this code:

```
function myFunction () {};
var myObj = { prop: myFunction };

myObj.prop === myFunction; // true
myObj.prop = 'changed';

typeof myFunction === 'function'; // true
myObj.prop === myFunction; // false
```

Changing `myObj.prop` did not change the original function, `myFunction` still exists in its own right. `myObj.prop`, however, has lost its reference to `myFunction`. If this was in sinon world, stubbing simply changed the reference of `myObj.prop` to a stub object.

This is why when testing code in a service which calls another function in the same service, that code needs to reference the same object returned by the service. If you want to avoid using the `this` keyword everywhere, you can structure your service like so:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('peopleService', peopleService);

peopleService.$inject = ['$q'];

function peopleService ($q){
  var service = {
    getFamily: getFamily,
    getAdults: getAdults
  };

  return service;

  function getFamily () {
     // ...
  }

  function getAdults (){
    var family = service.getFamily(); // <-- reference service.getFamily()
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer should get the reward, it is pretty clear and complete